# What is the path to Qt, and path to Qt's configure file on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5

I am following [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html) documentation for deployment. It need me to specify `/path/to/Qt` and `/path/to/Qt/configure`. I am unable to find the path to Qt on my machine.

I am using `Ubuntu 17` and I installed Qt using `apt install qt5-default`. Any idea where can I find it on Ubuntu, or how to find it?

*EDIT*: I found `qt5` at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/` but it does not have a `configure` file.

Comment: configure is a file that is in the source code, in the case of the Qt that ubuntu provides it will not have since using apt-get you install the binaries. If you want to use configure you must download the Qt source code: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt5.git/

Answer (score 0):

You can get Qt sources from Git and follow [Building Qt 5 from Git](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git). You can also download source tarball, e.g. [Qt 5.10.1](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.10/5.10.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1.tar.xz) or select some other version from [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/).

Extract the sources to your preferred location e.g. /home/user/qt. So, your sources are in /home/user/qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1. To keep sources clean create separate build and install dirs, e.g. /home/user/qt/build and /home/user/qt/install.

Go to the build dir:

```
cd /home/user/qt/build
```

Run configure from your build dir and give the install dir using -prefix:

```
../qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1/configure -static -prefix /home/<user>/qt/install <other parameters>
```

where "other parameters" are e.g.

```
-release -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine
```

(skip qtwebengine if you don't need it to save lots of build time)